# Create a Ms access form to edit the data in the database

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have one table EmployeeData. I have created one form based on that table where ID is a combobox. I have used Dlookup to auto populate other textboxes of the form such as Name, phone number etc.

I wish to have a form where I use ID field to autopopulate other textboxes, and then be able to edit the data in all the textboxes(i.e name and phone number) and save the updated data in the same table.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? So we can better help you find solutions.

Comment: Why are you using DLookup()? Use a bound form. This is basic Access functionality. Have you gone through an introductory tutorial?

Comment: I have done this after a bit research.

Private Sub Combotxt_Change()
Me.PFtxt = Me.Combotxt.Column(1)

This works.

But when I use another textbox and use column 4, it doesn't get updated.

Me.Nametxt = Me.Combotxt.Column(4)

This is not working.

Also after fetching these values, I want to update the values in the texboxes and then store the edited values into the same table via button click.